# Recursion function (subset) returns empty (python)

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a recursion function to get all subsets out of a list of integers. For example, given a list `[1, 2, 3]`, the return will be `[[],[1],[2],[3],[1, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3],[1, 2, 3]]`.

Here is my code:

```
def subsets(nums):

    def helper(subset, i):

        if i == len(nums):
            print('return = ', subset)
            res.append(subset)

        else:
            helper(subset, i+1)
            subset.append(nums[i])
            helper(subset, i+1)
            subset.remove(nums[i])

    res = []
    helper([], 0)
    return res
```

I print out the `subset` in each recursion and they are right. However, the final return `res` is always empty.

```
return =  []
return =  [3]
return =  [2]
return =  [2, 3]
return =  [1]
return =  [1, 3]
return =  [1, 2]
return =  [1, 2, 3]
res = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Anyone knows why? Appreciate it!

Comment: You might be interested in [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pretty close!  The issue is that `subset` is being appended to `res`, but later modified.  What you want is a "frozen" version of what `subset` *is then*, not a "reference" to what it will eventually be.

So instead of `res.append(subset)`, consider appending a copy of the list, for example with:

```
res.append(subset[:])
```

And you'll get your expected result:

```
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jedwards!